# Class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbfm extended by class com.google.android.gms.location.ActivityRecognitionResult is inaccessible

Tags: java, android, react-native, gradle, audioflinger

I'm currently trying to set up an android app called GoNote that I didn't write. The codebase is about a year old and uses React Native. However, there are Android-only and iOS-only dependencies.

I had much trouble just getting the project to sync and build in Android Studio. Now that I am able to compile the app, I run into a fatal error after I click on the start button of the IDE and the Android UI gives me a "GoNote keeps stopping" dialog. I tried different devices (Pixel, Nexux 6, Nexus S) with Oreo and also Nougat with the same result. I don't really know what else to do. The log is humongous and I have a hard time figuring out what's important and what's not.

I noticed the following log in Logcat when I try to tap on the app icon:

```
04-05 11:16:53.323 6348-6348/com.emberex.GoNote E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.emberex.GoNote, PID: 6348
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbfm extended by class com.google.android.gms.location.ActivityRecognitionResult is inaccessible (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.location.ActivityRecognitionResult' appears in /data/app/com.emberex.GoNote-PMng9irP3-f0hgYFm6Y0IA==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk:classes30.dex)
    at com.transistorsoft.rnbackgroundgeolocation.RNBackgroundGeolocationModule.<init>(RNBackgroundGeolocationModule.java:85)
    at com.transistorsoft.rnbackgroundgeolocation.RNBackgroundGeolocation.createNativeModules(RNBackgroundGeolocation.java:19)
    at com.facebook.react.NativeModuleRegistryBuilder.processPackage(NativeModuleRegistryBuilder.java:88)
    at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.processPackage(ReactInstanceManager.java:950)
    at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext(ReactInstanceManager.java:891)
    at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.access$600(ReactInstanceManager.java:104)
    at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$ReactContextInitAsyncTask.doInBackground(ReactInstanceManager.java:218)
    at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$ReactContextInitAsyncTask.doInBackground(ReactInstanceManager.java:197)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: `04-05 10:03:04.900 1601-6720/? E/AudioFlinger: not enough memory for AudioTrack size=131296` - that's the error that stood out for me. Look into the max size for an audio track and then see how big yours is

Comment: I've noticed the AudioFlinger error, but my research on stackoverflow did not help. I don't believe that the app uses audio. It's an app that uses geolocation heavily, though.

Comment: I was able to remove the AudioFlinger error by increasing the memory of the SD card in the Advanced Settings of my virtual device. However, the app still doesn't run. I've updated the question with the new log.

Answer (score 0):

I addeed this in `app/build.gradle`

```
 implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:19.0.1")
```

now works for me